# Timing an operation without being affected by clock changes

Tags: time, go

I'm looking for:

```
1: startTime := time.Now()

2: // run something here that takes a while (measured in milliseconds)

3: duration := time.Since(startTime)
```

However, I need something that is immune to clock time changes. If the time is adjusted between lines 1 and 3, the duration will be inaccurate.

What are some common approaches for solving this problem, and what Go libraries could be relevant?

Thanks :)

Comment: I think https://github.com/davecheney/junk/tree/master/clock may be what you want? Some discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/D11F4zMs-E0

Comment: 4 years later, with Go 1.9, you now have a monotonic clock. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45907491/6309).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That lack of monotonic clock was detailed in [issue 12914](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12914) (2015)

Since then, in August 2017 and Go 1.9, you now have a [transparent Monotonic Time support](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#monotonic-time):

> The [`time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) package now transparently tracks monotonic time in each [`Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) value, **making computing durations between two `Time` values a safe operation in the presence of wall clock adjustments**.
>   See the [package docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#hdr-Monotonic_Clocks) and [design document](https://golang.org/design/12914-monotonic) for details.

Answer (score 2):

For Linux (AMD64) go uses `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_REALTIME`. 
See the [`time·now` implementation](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/runtime/sys_linux_amd64.s?name=go1.1.2#103).

You would want a monotonic clock (`CLOCK_MONOTONIC` or `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`), which
is a clock that does not go back in time. In Linux the man page explicitly tells you that `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` does not guarantee to not leap forward:

> This clock is not affected by discontinuous jumps in the system time (e.g., if the system  administrator
>     manually  changes  the  clock),  but  is affected by the incremental adjustments performed by adjtime(3) and NTP.

So, under Linux, the best choice is probably `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`. You may use the 
[clock package](https://github.com/davecheney/junk/tree/master/clock) [mentioned by @MatrixFrog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647856/timing-an-operation-without-being-affected-by-clock-changes/19673155#comment29176721_19647856) for that. Example:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/davecheney/junk/clock"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    start := clock.Monotonic.Now()
    // work
    end := clock.Monotonic.Now()

    duration := end.Sub(start)

    fmt.Println("Elapsed:", duration)
}
```

Further reading:

- [Discussion about monotonic clocks in go](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/YYi57cFhnL4/1cMPzEdwzcEJ)
- [Outlook to get a clock interface in the go stdlib](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/D11F4zMs-E0/4B4TRtvA57YJ)